# What is the version compatibility for spring boot with Couchbase 6.6?

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to connect to Couchbase server 6.6 using Spring Boot application  and I want to use username and password to connect to Couchbase server. Which Spring boot version is compatible for this ? And what are configuration I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please just read the documentation. For the compatability it says [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.migrating):

> Please note that implicitly the minimum Couchbase Server version has been bumped up to 5.5 and later, and we recommend running at least 6.0.x.

And the configuration can be done like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration-java):

```java
@Configuration
public class Config extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getConnectionString() {
        return "couchbase://127.0.0.1";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return "Administrator";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "password";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBucketName() {
        return "travel-sample";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Garuno, For the version part , if my spring boot version is 2.1.3.RELEASE then it will not work with spring-data-couchbase 3.1.5.RELEASE  version  right ?

Comment: From the most recent documentation I would say it should work, but it is better to check the docs for the older versions.